# What pollifills do I need to ran an Angular 10 App on chrome v.40?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, polyfills

I'm trying to run a an Angular 10 CLI app on older browsers -

- Chrome 40
- IE 11

The app would not load at all and these are the errors I get from the Chrome browser

- **zone-evergreen.js** throws error - **Uncaught SyntaxError - Use of const in strict mode**
- **animatin.js** throws error - **Uncaught SyntaxError - Use of const in strict mode**
- **approuting.modul.ts** throws error - **Uncaught SyntaxError - Use of const in strict mode**

[image: li]
Are there any poilyfills I should use to get this runnng and how do I implement these polyfills?

Comment: If you use only ts, just change target in tsonfig to es5.